# Missing private key

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, private-key, ios-provisioning

I add my ios developer account to xCode and I got this:

[image: Missing private key]

I installed all certificates and provision profiles on my mac.

What does it mean and how can I solve it.

Comment: From which machine have you created Certificate Signing Request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the certificate on the same machine from which you've created your CSR. Then go to your KeyChain, expand the certificate, select both certificate and PrivateKey and export them to `.p12` format.

In your new machine import the `.p12` file. You'll have both `Certificate` along with `Private Key`